# how to create report when we need to get fields from ten different objects

Tags: apex, visualforce, reporting

I have ten objects now i want to show different fields of the different objects in one report how to achieve this

Comment: Are all ten objects directly related?

Comment: yes they are related to each other

Answer (score 0):

You can use formula field or trigger based on the objects have relationship or not to populate the data on the object you are trying to create report. This could resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Presuming that all of the objects can be reached by a single SOQL (in other words, there is one "bottom" level object, and all other objects are ancestors, and there's no more than four levels of relationships involved), you can build a Custom Report Type. So, for example, let's say you have the following 10 objects:

```
A       B       C
 \     / \     /
  D   E   F   G
   \ /     \ /
    H       I
     \     /
      \   /
       \ /
        J
```

Select J as the original report object, then add in fields using relationship lookups. Note that this isn't the only possible configuration, but the general rules will still apply. There must be one bottom-most object you can query by, and the remaining objects must be no more than great-great-grandparents of the bottom-most object. There's also hard limits about how many relationships you can include in a report, but this report should easily be within those limits.

Comment: yeah i understood what you said but these are not related as we have in your diagram its in very typically related so we are trying to make a object put all required fields and then we are trying to update the fields using trigger and then we are trying to make a report on that object. i was trying to do it using configuration but was not able to make it